# How to send an SMS from an iPhone automatically without jailbreaking

Tags: ios, iphone

As far as I am aware (please let me know if this is not the case), all versions of iOS, including iOS 8 do not allow automatic text messages sent from the iPhone without user input. This is possible with jailbreaking, but not in a normal app.

However I was reading that it was possible to send an SMS message to a server and then send it out. Would you be able to do this from the user's phone number? What iOS API would be involved in this? MessageUI?

I can find almost no information about this at all - it seems like not a very common use-case. My goal is to make an automatic texting application that is configurable by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up Parse cloud code (Parse is free for 20GB data + 1800 requests / minute ) that calls a Twilio client ($1/mo per phone number + something like .075 cents a text) that makes your texts for you.  You would not be able to set the 'from' number as anything other than a Twilio number you own or a number you've verified as your own.  An issue with this is that if the person who receives the text replies to it, you can pretty much only have your code set up to do one thing when a user texts each number.  So if you want each user to be able to text 100 different people you need to have 100 different numbers.

Comment: Is there anyway for the users to verify their numbers for this service?

Comment: If you mean so that a text can be sent from their number, then no.  That's something you do through the Twilio console, and it's so that your business phone number can be the one that users call back.  If you mean so that you can verify a phone number is theirs, I just wrote an app that takes in a user's phone number and sends a random 4 digit verification code to the user, and they have to enter it to move on in the registration process.

Comment: No, I definitely would want to send a text from their phone number.